# Django SubQuery Error when Building a Recipient List for send_mail() based on Custom Permission

Tags: python, django, html-email

I am trying to code a recipients list for send_mail() that will query for users with a custom permission and place them in the list. The purpose is to use Django admin to make it easier on the user to place users into a group with this permission to receive the email. I am receiving this `more than one row returned by a subquery`. I am using modelBase which has a few child models so the custom permission attaches it self to more then one model. How can I adjust my code to clear this error and produce the recipients list I need.

Here are my models.py and views.py. I apologize if the formatting is off, I didn't want to clutter up the question with unnecessary info. 
models.py:

```
class StoreNightlyReportsBase(models.Model):
    store_nightly_report = models.ForeignKey(StoreNightlyReport)
    no_new_item = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Check if No New Items", default=False)
    customer = models.CharField(verbose_name='Customer Name', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = (('nightly_reports','Nightly Reports'),
                       )


class StoreNightlyReportsNewLoan(StoreNightlyReportsBase):
    ...


class StoreNightlyReportsRenewals(StoreNightlyReportsBase):
    ...
```

views.py

```
class StoresNightlyReportsNewLoansCreate(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...


        perm = Permission.objects.filter(codename='nightly_reports')
        users = User.objects.filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm)).distinct()
        recipients = list(i for i in users.values_list('email', flat=True) if bool(i))
        html_email = render_to_string('reports/email.html', {
            'object': self.object,
            'user': self.request.user,
        })
        send_mail(
            'Nightly Numbers',
            'Here is the message.',
            'emailp@company.com',
            [recipients],
            html_message=html_email,
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    return super(StoresNightlyReportsNewLoansCreate, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The broader question here is to allow an end user to use the Django Admin to move users into groups with specific permissions to receive an email. The direct question was to use permissions to accomplish this task but an error was being thrown.

I decided to answer the broader question. In doing so I changed my approach slightly. In this approach the end-user-admin will just move users into a group designed specifically to received emails. Now I can just search for the group based on the authenticate user, pull the emails in that group into a list and then add that to the recipients in send_mail().

The code is as follows:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        groups = self.request.user.groups.filter(name__startswith='Nightly Reports')
        recipients = list(User.objects.filter(
            email__contains='@',
            groups__in=groups).values_list('email', flat=True))

        html_email = render_to_string('reports/email.html', {
                'object': self.object,
                'user': self.request.user,
        })
        send_mail(
            'Nightly Numbers',
            'Here is the message.',
            'company@company.com',
            recipients,
            html_message=html_email,
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

This works in answer the broader question and removes the error thrown from the direct question by not using a query on permissions.